# How to get the sum of hours worked from a range of dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the trfdespacio table where the operator number, the date of departure and the date of arrival are registered.

[image: trfdespacho]

I have the trfdespacho table where the operator number, the date of departure and the date of arrival are registered.
I want to get the time worked in hours and minutes between the date of departure and the date of arrival to later obtain the time that I rest.
For example there is a registered date of the day 10 March 1:14 and finishes the same day 10 of March to the 9:25, the labor time is of 8 hours with 11 minutes.
With continuous Labor time to obtain the time that I rest in 1 day,
How can I do it if I am requested to report the date from March 10 to March 11
As I can get the time I work on those two days and the time I rest.

I have the following with which I only get the total amount of time I work in 1 day as I can do for more days.

```
SELECT 
    D.numOperador,
(cast(SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, D.FechaSalida, D.FechaLlegada)) / 60 as varchar)  + +':'+
cast( SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, D.FechaSalida, D.FechaLlegada)) % 60 AS varchar )  ) as TiempoLaborado
    FROM 
    trkOperadores O
    INNER JOIN trfDespacho D ON O.NumOperador = D.numOperador
WHERE O.NumOperador = 900200 
    AND D.FechaSalida>='2017-03-10 00:00:00.000' AND D.FechaLlegada<=DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2017-03-10 00:00:00.000') 
GROUP BY 
    D.NumOperador, FechaSalida, FechaLlegada
GO
```

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Do you need that LaborTime and RestTime per day like March 10, March 11, etc. ? Or you need the continuous Labor and Rest time between Start and End date given in the query filter?

Comment: The second question I need the time worked and rested continuous between the start and end date according to the query filter

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to calculate the working and non-working time, then use what you already have to sum it and convert it to the HH:MM format you want.

Just creating test data...

```
drop table #test

create table #test (depart datetime, arrive datetime)
insert into #test values ('1-1-2017 10:00:00', '1-1-2017 10:15:00')
insert into #test values ('1-1-2017 11:00:00', '1-1-2017 11:25:00')
insert into #test values ('1-1-2017 11:25:00', '1-1-2017 11:56:00')
insert into #test values ('1-2-2017 13:05:00', '1-2-2017 15:00:00')
insert into #test values ('1-3-2017 13:05:00', '1-3-2017 15:00:00')
insert into #test values ('1-3-2017 20:00:00', '1-4-2017 1:00:00')
insert into #test values ('1-4-2017 13:05:00', '1-4-2017 15:00:00')
```

Set your window:

```
declare @begin datetime = '1-1-2017 00:00:00'
declare @end datetime = '1-3-2017 23:59:59'
```

Use `lead` to pick up the next departure time for each trip.  Then use `datediff` to figure out the time between the departure and arrival (or the beginning of the window and the arrival, if the departure was before your window started) and the arrival or the end of the window.

Then use `datediff` to figure out the time between the arrival and the next departure.

```
; with cte as (
    select *
        , lead(depart) over (order by depart, arrive) as NextDeparture 
    from #test
    where depart between @begin and @end 
        or arrive between @begin and @end)

select *
    , datediff(minute, case when depart < @begin then @begin else depart end, case when arrive > @end then @end else arrive end) as WorkTime
    , datediff(minute, case when arrive > @end then @end else arrive end, case when arrive > @end or nextdeparture is null then @end else nextdeparture end) as NonWorkTime
from cte
```

Note: you could also calculate the total duration of the window and just subtract the work time to get the non-work time.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you,

```
DECLARE
    @FirstDate datetime,
    @LastDate datetime

SELECT
    @FirstDate = '2017-03-11 00:00:00.000',
    @LastDate = '2017-03-14 00:00:00.000';

With A as (
Select '2017-03-10 09:00:00.000' as S, '2017-03-10 17:00:00.000' as E union 
Select '2017-03-11 09:00:00.000' as S, '2017-03-11 17:00:00.000' as E union 
Select '2017-03-12 09:00:00.000' as S, '2017-03-12 17:00:00.000' as E union 
Select '2017-03-13 09:00:00.000' as S, '2017-03-13 17:00:00.000' as E union 
Select '2017-03-14 09:00:00.000' as S, '2017-03-14 17:00:00.000' as E 
)

Select 
Sum(DATEDIFF(minute, S, E)) as [Worked Minutes], 
DATEDIFF(minute, @FirstDate, @LastDate) as [Total Duration in Minutes], 
DATEDIFF(minute, @FirstDate, @LastDate) - Sum(DATEDIFF(minute, S, E)) as [Rested Minutes]
-- You need to convert the rested minutes to hours and probably in days if it exeeds the 24 hours limit
from A 
Where S >= @FirstDate and E <= @LastDate
```